# Required field marked as ng-valid on keypress, even when it's empty

Tags: javascript, angular, validation

I'm using Angular 2 and I'm facing a rather basic issue on form validation. A required text field that's supposed to be numeric, is marked valid after the first keydown event, regardless of the value I enter and I'm not able to guess why.

Here's the control (I'm using Jade templates):

```
input.form-control(required, type='number', [(ngModel)]='details.averageAnnualVisitorCount', placeholder='Example: 5000000')
```

Initially, the control is marked ng-pristine and ng-invalid as expected:

```
<input class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" placeholder="Example: 5000000" required="required" type="number">
```

But when I focus on the field and press any key (even an invalid one), the control is marked valid and I'm not sure why. For instance, I tried Z which was rejected because of using `type='number'`, but the field is still marked `ng-valid` as shown below:

```
<input class="form-control ng-dirty ng-valid ng-touched" placeholder="Example: 5000000" required="required" type="number">
```

Shouldn't this be ng-ditry ng-invalid and ng-touched instead? I also tried adding ngControl, thinking that I'm missing some behavior associated with ngControl classes, but that didn't change the behaviour either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with number and select fields

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8048
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6527
  It looks like this will be fixed in the next beta

Answer (score 0):

I to ran into this problem when trying to color code my forum for showing validation. I used [ng-pattern](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern) to fix it. Perhaps try that? I know that there is a simple reg expression that you can use to detect numbers. [Check out here](http://regexone.com/lesson/letters_and_digits) for reg expression help.